# Applicative's Interchange Law

Tags: haskell

[Applicative Programming with Effects](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html), the paper from McBride and Paterson, presents the **interchange law**:

`u <*> pure x = pure (\f -> f x) <*> u`

In order to try to understand it, I attempted the following example - to represent the left-hand side.

```
ghci> Just (+10) <*> pure 5
Just 15
```

How could I write this example using the right-hand side?

Also, if `u` is an `f (a -> b)` where `f` is an `Applicative`, then what's the function on the right-hand side: `pure (\f -> f x) ...`?

Comment: To get an intuition, since `pure` has no effects, in both `u <*> pure x` and `pure ($ x) <*> u`, the only effectful part is `u`, so it doesn't matter if you left- or right-combine it with no effects whatsoever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be written as

```
pure (\f -> f 5) <*> Just (+10)
```

Or even

```
pure ($ 5) <*> Just (+10)
```

Both are equivalent in this case.  Quite literally, you're wrapping a function with `pure` that takes another function as its argument, then applies `x` to it.  You provide `f` as the contents of the `Just`, which in this case is `(+10)`.  When you see the lambda syntax of `(\f -> f x)`, it's being very literal, this is a lambda used for this definition.

Answer (score 3):

The point this law makes is about preservation of exponential by the `Applicative` Functor: what is a exponential in the origin, is also an exponential in the image of the category.

Please, observe that the actual action of the `Applicative` Functor is the transformation of the following kind: `strength :: (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)`; then `ap` or `<*>` is just `fmap eval` over the result, or, written fully, `ap = curry $ fmap (uncurry ($)) . strength`.

This law then says that since in the origin `g $ x == ($ x) $ g`, lifting `($)`, `x` and `($ x)` should preserve the equality. Notice, that "normal" `Functor`s will only preserve the equality only if `g` is lifted, too, but `Applicative` Functors will preserve this equality for any object of type `f (a->b)` in place of `g`. This way the whole type `f (a->b)` behaves like `f a -> f b`, whereas for "normal" `Functor`s it only needs to behave like `f a -> f b` for images of the arrows in the origin (to make the diagrams commute and fulfill the promises of the `Functor`).

As to representing the right-hand-side of the law, you've already been advised to take it literally, `pure ($ 5) <*> Just (+10)`