# How to apply a traversable of functions to a one value

Tags: list, function, haskell, apply, traversable

What should I use if I want to have something like

```
[a->b] -> a -> [b]
```

basically I have a list of functions, all take in a value `a` and returns `b`. I want to apply all of them to one `a` and get the results `[b]`.

Which one should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You don't need `Traversable`, just `Functor`:

```hs
swingMap f x = fmap ($ x) f
```

See also [the `swing` function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree#Swing) (this is equivalent to `swing fmap`).

---

Or, if you're using [Edward Kmett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34707/edward-kmett)'s [`distributive` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.1), you can have the best of both this answer (only a `Functor` rather than a `Traversable`) and [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60610107/7509065) (avoiding defining a custom function for the job), by using [`distribute` from Data.Distributive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:distribute).

Comment: `??` from lens (and relude) also serve this purpose and are built into common libraries.

Comment: @MikaelF It's the same as my `swingMap`, but if you're using a third-party library anyway, `distribute` is more general than it is.

Comment: They're identical, and also only require a functor. I just wanted to name them as a side note.

Comment: @MikaelF They're not identical. There's a lot of `Distributive` instances, and `distribute` works on them all, but `??` only works on functions.

Comment: `fmap ($ x) t` is way easier to understand than `distribute t x`. Oof!

Answer (score 6):

You could use `sequence`, specialized to the `(->) a` monad. In this way you can avoid defining a custom function for the job -- it's already there.

```
> :t sequence
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
> :t sequence :: [a->b] -> a -> [b]
sequence :: [a->b] -> a -> [b] :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
> sequence [id,(10+),(10-)] 3
[3,13,7]
```

(`sequenceA` and `traverse id`, being the same, would also work)

Comment: This definitely looks like overkill, as the other answer shows.

Comment: Although having thought about this a bit more, I found a solution that combines the benefits of both ways (edited into my answer now).

Comment: @dfeuer I don't know what's overkill in this context. The OP only asked for a specific function on lists of functions. Both my answer and Joseph's (after the edit) use a general library function to do the job. Perhaps it's overkill because it's general? Is it better to use a custom function? I am unsure. Note that nowadays `sequence` is in scope without importing anything, so it's not completely unreasonable to ask that the programmer understands it.

Comment: @chi I think dfeuer's point was that the `Traversable` constraint is overkill.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It's a matter of perspective. If you need it on lists, and lists only, like the OP asked, `Traversable []` is satisfied, so no constraint remains to be required from the user. If you want to generalize it to other "containers", and you need a constraint which can not be solved immediately, then I agree with you.

Comment: I mostly meant that the *idea* of `sequence` is overkill when the significantly simpler idea of `fmap` will do. And using reader here seems excessive. The constraint is also stronger than needed, which you've justified but I find a bit sad.

Comment: @dfeuer `fmap` is significantly simpler, but that alone does not solve the problem; we need `\f x -> fmap ($ x) f` which is not as simple, IMO. I don't think there's a completely objective notion of "simpler" here. To me, we need to turn `[a->b]` into `a->[b]`, i.e. commuting `[]` and `a ->`, which `sequence`/`distribute` do nicely and simply. Others might disagree, of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

When functions appear in a data type it's time to remember applicatives because that's what it is. One might easily do this job like;

```
appList :: [a->b] -> a -> [b]
appList fs x = fs <*> pure x

λ> appList [(+1), (*2), subtract 3] 5
[6,10,2]
```

Comment: The interchange law can (and IMO should) be applied there.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I had to look up for [The Interchange Law on Applicatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27285918/4543207) but cant really tell what's the catch.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, the existence of the special cases `fs <*> pure x` and `pure f <*> xs` inspired me to rewrite the `Applicative` instance for `Data.Sequence`. Interestingly, the `fs <*> pure x` case proved to be a *far* more productive starting point in that process.